# Looping through nested list that contains dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

Hi how can I loop through n below, and get the dictionary elements in e if the elements are a match.

```
e = [(1001, 7005, {'length': 0.35, 'modes': 'cw', 'type': '99', 'lanes': 9}),
     (1002, 8259, {'length': 0.35, 'modes': 'cw', 'type': '99', 'lanes': 9}), (1001, 14007, {'length': 0.35, 'modes': 'cw', 'type': '99', 'lanes': 9})]

n = [[(1001, 7005), (3275, 8925)], [(1598, 6009), (1001, 14007)]]
```

ie compare n and if n is in e print the dictionary

```
b = []
for d in n:
    for items in d:
        print b
```

outcome should be

```
output = [[{'length': 0.35, 'modes': 'cw', 'type': '99', 'lanes': 9}],[{'length': 0.35, 'modes': 'cw', 'type': '99', 'lanes': 9}]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a mapping (dictionary) from the `e` list and [flatten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python) `n` list of list of tuples into list of tuples:

```
e = [(1001, 7005, {'length': 0.35, 'modes': 'cw', 'type': '99', 'lanes': 9}),
     (1002, 8259, {'length': 0.35, 'modes': 'cw', 'type': '99', 'lanes': 9}),
     (1001, 14007, {'length': 0.35, 'modes': 'cw', 'type': '99', 'lanes': 9})]

n = [[(1001, 7005),(3275, 8925)], [(1598,6009),(1001,14007)]]

d = {(item[0], item[1]): item[2] for item in e}
n = [item for sublist in n for item in sublist]

print [d[item] for item in n if item in d]
```

prints:

```
[{'lanes': 9, 'length': 0.35, 'type': '99', 'modes': 'cw'}, 
 {'lanes': 9, 'length': 0.35, 'type': '99', 'modes': 'cw'}]
```

Comment: Thanks, however the output should be the dictionary alone as @thefourtheye has it

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the `e` list to a dictionary, with dictionary comprehension, like this

```
f = {(v1, v2):v3 for v1, v2, v3 in e}
```

Then, we can flatten `n` and check if each of the element is in `f` or not. If it is there, then we can get the value corresponding to that from `f`, like this

```
from itertools import chain
print [f[item] for item in chain.from_iterable(n) if item in f]
```

**Output**

```
[{'lanes': 9, 'length': 0.35, 'modes': 'cw', 'type': '99'},
 {'lanes': 9, 'length': 0.35, 'modes': 'cw', 'type': '99'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension:

```
[e1[2] for e1 in e for n1 in n for n2 in n1 if (e1[0]==n2[0] and e1[1]==n2[1])]
```

Output:

```
[{'lanes': 9, 'length': 0.35, 'type': '99', 'modes': 'cw'}, 
 {'lanes': 9, 'length': 0.35, 'type': '99', 'modes': 'cw'}]
```

Comment: Thanks, however the output should be the dictionary alone as @thefourtheye has it

Comment: But strangely the output of your code is an empty list on my machine, could it be as a result of different python versions? I use python 2.7